# jQuery Validate setDefaults for input type

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validation library to validate forms on on my site before submitting them. I'd like to use one `validate()` function for all my forms which works great with just adding the `required` attribute to form inputs. But I've run into a snag.

I want to use validation methods from the `additional-methods.js` library to validate phone numbers and other special inputs. In my `validate()` function I would just add the following.

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        user_phone: {
           phoneUS: true,
        },
    },
});
```

But that only works on inputs with the `name='user_phone'`. I have forms with more than one phone input. Is there a way to use the `phoneUS` validation method on all inputs with `type='tel'`?

Thanks in advance to anyone who offers any insight on this.

***Edit***

I'm looking for something like this...

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
   rules: {
      'type=tel': {
         phoneUS: true,
      },
   },    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot declare rules within `.validate()` or `.setDefaults()` by anything other than one `name` at a time.

> Is there a way to use the `phoneUS` validation method on all inputs with `type='tel'`?

Yes, with [the `.rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/), you can use any jQuery selector and target multiple input elements at once.

```
$('input[type="tel"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        phoneUS: true,
        // other rules
    });
});
```

- You **must** still have a unique `name` on each input element.
- You must use a jQuery `.each()` when the selector contains multiple elements.
- You must still use the `.validate()` method to initialize the plugin on your form.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/fqss7uy3/**

Comment: Ahhh that's perfect. Thanks Sparky!